# How to set NSButton's keyEquivalent to NSDownArrowFunctionKey in Swift

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, nsbutton

How do I set an NSButton's keyEquivalent (which is a String type) to the down arrow key in Swift? NSDownArrowFunctionKey is an Int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Tasks/SettingButtonKeyEquiv.html) in Apple's documentation addresses this exact issue. The example they provide is written in Objective-C, the Swift equivalent is as follows:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: NSButton!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

        var array = [unichar(NSDownArrowFunctionKey)]
        button.keyEquivalent = NSString(characters: array, length: 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I added `as String` to the end of the `NSString` call. Alternatively, `String(utf16CodeUnits: array, count: 1)` also seems to work.